# Entity Framework Code First using virtual property internally, null reference when called

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am completely new to Entity Framework. I have created a model to watch services on remote machines. Currently it looks like this:

***Note:*** I have done my best to use understandable generic names since this is from a corporate environment.

```cs
public class RemoteService
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MachineName")]
    public virtual RemoteEnvironment RunningAt { get; set; }
}

public class RemoteEnvironment
{
    [Key]
    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    public string Configuration { get; set; }

    public string EnvironmentNr { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RemoteService> Services { get; set; }
}
```

With context class:

```cs
public class MyDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<RemoteEnvironment> RemoteEnvironments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RemoteService> RemoteServices { get; set; }
}
```

This model works fine when creating the database and seeding it. The `RemoteService` class also contains this `Version` property, to get the version from the Octopus Deploy API.

```cs
private string _version = "N/A";
public string Version
{
    get
    {
        var item = GetItemFromOctopus(Name, RunningAt.EnvironmentNr);
        if (item != null)
        {
            _version = item.ReleaseVersion;
        }
        return _version;
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

This also works fine when creating and seeding the database. My issue appears when I try to grab data from the database. Something like this:

```cs
using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var serviceNames = new List<string>(); 
    foreach (RemoteService service in context.RemoteServices)
    {
        serviceNames.Add(service.Name); 
    }
}
```

While executing the above code I get a `NullReferenceException`, because `RunningAt` is null.
[image: NullReference]

From debugging I have gathered that it is when I grab `service` from `context.RemoteServices` that it fetches all the properties. First `Name`, then `MachineName`, skips `RunningAt` **(why? Lazy Loading?)** and then tries to get `Version`, but since `RunningAt` is null, it can't.

I have tried defining the `RunningAt` get and set methods using

```cs
private RemoteEnvironment _runningAt
```

but the issue stays the same, both `RunningAt` and `_runningAt` are null while fetching data from the database.

It seems that I somehow need to load the reference to the `RemoteEnvironment` from the database in the get of `Version`. But creating a context here seems a bit much.

What else can I do? I would really like to keep `Version` as is. If it can't be done, I will have to make a workaround. Checking version separately, actively getting and setting it instead.

**Edit 1:**
I have now tried three different ways to "pre-load" the `RemoteEnvironments`.

**First:**
"Pre-loading" by getting all `RemoteEnvironments` from database.

```cs
using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var serviceNames = new List<string>();
    List<M3BEnvironment> activateEnv = db.M3BEnvvironments.ToList(); //added line
    foreach (RemoteService service in context.RemoteServices)
    {
        serviceNames.Add(service.Name); 
    }
}
```

Still getting NullReferenceException since RunningAt is null.

**Second:**
Removing the virtual keyword.

```cs
[ForeignKey("MachineName")]
public RemoteEnvironment RunningAt { get; set; } // virtual keyword removed
```

Still getting NullReferenceException since RunningAt is null.

**Third:**
Using `Include` to force eagerly loading.

```cs
using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var serviceNames = new List<string>(); 
    var services = context.RemoteServices.Include(s => s.RunningAt).ToList();
    foreach (RemoteService service in services)
    {
        serviceNames.Add(service.Name); 
    }
}
```

Still getting NullReferenceException since RunningAt is null.

I have even tried all combinations of the above, including all three at the same time. **Still getting NullReferenceException since RunningAt is null.**

I also tried going the other way, through `RemoteEnvironments` and including `Services`:

```cs
using (MyDBContext context = new MyDBContext())
{
    var environments = context.RemoteEnvironments.Include(env => env.Services).ToList(); // NullRefereceException happens at this call
    var serviceNames = new List<string>(); 
    var services = context.RemoteServices.Include(s => s.RunningAt).ToList();
    foreach (RemoteService service in services)
    {
        serviceNames.Add(service.Name); 
    }
}
```

Still getting NullReferenceException since RunningAt is null. Only this time it happens while the `environments` call is trying to include them.

**What I want to do does not seem possible.** Using the referenced `RunningAt` property within the `Version` property, because it is never loaded from the database. Not even when I force it to load the `RemoteEnvironments` before the call to the `RemoteService` and subsequently the call to `Version`.

Comment: Because `RunningAt` is in `context.RemoteEnvironments` and not `context.RemoteServices` where you're trying to get it from I guess

Comment: @jamiedanq Well, yeah. That is the issue at hand. I want to be able to reference that inside the `Version` property. Preferably, without having to create a new database reference. The more I think about it, the more I lean toward finding a workaround instead.

Comment: why don't you grab all the `RemoteEnvironments` from the db first before getting the Version?

Comment: @jamiedanq See my edit please.

Comment: Since `Version` get method is actually setting the version, by getting it from octopus, maybe this should be in the set instead and get is just `return _version`?

Comment: Apparently both the get and set methods are called, so it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I am trying to do does not seem possible.** The core issue is having a navigation property and then referencing it in another property's get or set method. This does not seem to work. I have tried turning off lazy loading, forcing loading with `Include` and also pre-loading the DbSet which the navigation property points to. In each and every case the navigation property reference, in my case `RunningAt`, has been null inside the other property's get/set method.

The Entity Framework does not seem to support referencing a navigation property inside another property. If anyone knows otherwise please tell me how. In the mean time, this will be the accepted answer.